# Using base class methods from derived class - error

Tags: c++, string, class, inheritance

I'm doing a small project for a university essay, and I've run into some trouble.

I have a class `publication` that has the fields headline and text, defined like this (this is the header file):

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using std::string;

class publication
{
    private:
        string headline,text;
    public:
        publication(); //constructor

        void set_headline(const string new_headline);
        void set_text(const string new_text);

        string get_headline();
        string get_text();

        void print();
};
```

And this is the implementation (.cpp file):

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "publication.h"

using namespace std;
using std::string;

publication::publication()
{
    headline="";
    text="";
}

void publication::set_headline(const string new_headline)
{
    headline=new_headline; //any input is valid
}

void publication::set_text(const string new_text)
{
    text=new_text; //any input is valid
}

string publication::get_headline()
{
    return headline;
}

string publication::get_text()
{
    return text;
}
```

This is the base class.

We also have a derived class called `article` that inherits from `publication`, but has the added field of author. it is defined like this (header file):

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "publication.h"

using namespace std;
using std::string;

class article: public publication
{
    private:
        string author;
    public:
        article();

        void set_author(const string new_author);

        string get_author();
        string ToString();
};
```

And this is the implementation (.cpp file)

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "article.h"

using namespace std;
using std::string;

article::article(): publication()
{
    author="";
}

void article::set_author(const string new_author)
{
    author=new_author;
}

string article::get_author()
{
    return author;
}

string article::ToString()
{
    string ToReturn;
    ToReturn = "Author: " + author + '\n' + article.get_headline() + '\n' + article.get_text();
    return ToReturn;
}
```

Just to test that everything works, I wrote the following main function:

```
#pragma once
#include "article.h"
#include "news.h"
#include "notice.h"
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
using std::string;

void main()
{
    article MyArticle;

    MyArticle.set_author("Thomas H. Cormen");
    MyArticle.set_headline("Introduction to Algorithms");
    MyArticle.set_text("Dijkstra's algorithm is an algorithm for finding the shortest paths between nodes in a graph.");

    cout << MyArticle.ToString();
    getch();
}
```

But when I compile it, I get the error "illegal use of this type as an expression".

It says the error comes from the line "`ToReturn = "Author: " + author + '\n' + article.get_headline() + '\n' + article.get_text();`"

I don't know any workaround this. I cant access text and headline directly since they are not class members of article, and I can't use the getters for some unknown reason either it seems.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`article` is a class, it cannot be used to the left of `.` (only objects can). You actually don't need the qualification there at all:

```
ToReturn = "Author: " + author + '\n' + get_headline() + '\n' + get_text();
```

If, for some reason, you really wanted to qualify the inherited members, you'd use the scope resolution operator (`::`) for that:

```
ToReturn = "Author: " + author + '\n' + article::get_headline() + '\n' + article::get_text();
```

But remember, you *do not* have to do this here (and under most coding conventions, you *should not*). If the functions were virtual, for example, qualifying them explicitly could even be the wrong thing to do (as it would suppress virtual dispatch).

Comment: If you already mention that he can use `::`, imho you should also mention that he can use `this->`. I am not familiar with any coding convention (but my own), but I think `this->` can make code much clearer in some cases